# extract typescript files from deployed files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've accidently deleted my typescript files. I don't have any backup of this code. I have deployed and bundled typescript files with **`ng build --prod`**  command in **dist** folder  and the application works fine on web server. is there any way to extract and recover typescript files from bundled  javascript files? 
this is content of dist folder :

[image: this is content of dist folder]

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but there is no such reverse engg way :(

Comment: ok , thanks anshu , if you sure about that i ' m gonna die :)

Comment: Maybe from map files? You can try this old tool: https://github.com/timmc/unsourcemap

Comment: Are you not using any form of Source Versioning?

Comment: Unfortunately no , i have a back up from four days ago , and many changes in these 4 days

Comment: Thanks Paleo , i try that , but i don't think that works